# class inheritance + lombok + javac = compilation error

Tags: inheritance, javac, lombok

In Eclipse the following setup all compiles and runs just fine.
However, when using javac on the code, compiling `LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass` results in compiler errors.

My Files:

```
package stackoverflow.lombok.inheritanceproblem;

import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;

@UtilityClass
public class AOPString {

    static public String toLower(final String pString) {
        return pString == null ? null : pString.toLowerCase();
    }

}
```

and

```
package stackoverflow.lombok.inheritanceproblem;

import lombok.experimental.ExtensionMethod;

@ExtensionMethod({ AOPString.class })
public class LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass o = new LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass();
        o.method1_normal();
        o.method2_overridden();
        o.method3_final();
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    public LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass() {
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass()".toLower());
    }

    public void method1_normal() {
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.method1_normal()".toLower());
    }
    public void method2_overridden() {
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.method2_normal()".toLower());
    }
    public final void method3_final() {
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.method3_final()".toLower());
    }

}
```

and

```
package stackoverflow.lombok.inheritanceproblem;

import lombok.experimental.ExtensionMethod;

@ExtensionMethod({ AOPString.class })
public class LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass extends LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass o = new LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass();
        o.method1_normal();
        o.method2_overridden();
        o.method3_final();
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    public LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass() {
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass.LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass()".toLower());
    }

    @Override public void method2_overridden() {
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass.method2_overridden()".toLower());
    }

}
```

As I stated already, Eclipse compilation of both files works without problems.

Compiling class `LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass` by calling `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javac.exe" D:\workspace\Test\src\stackoverflow\lombok\inheritanceproblem\LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.java -encoding utf8 -cp D:\lombok.jar -sourcepath D:\workspace\Test\src -d D:\apps-jc\libs_test\JcLib__AOP_Lombok_Test\jar-contents` also compiles and produces runnable code (that I later wrap up in an executable jar, which runs fine.

`D:\apps-jc\libs_test\JcLib__AOP_Lombok_Test\jar-contents` is emptied in between compilations.

When I try to compile the code of `LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass` with the command `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javac.exe" D:\workspace\Test\src\stackoverflow\lombok\inheritanceproblem\LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass.java -encoding utf8 -cp D:\lombok.jar -sourcepath D:\workspace\Test\src -d D:\apps-jc\libs_test\JcLib__AOP_Lombok_Test\jar-contents`  I get this interesting exception:

```
D:\workspace\Test\src\stackoverflow\lombok\inheritanceproblem\LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass()".toLower());
                                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   method toLower()
  location: class String
D:\workspace\Test\src\stackoverflow\lombok\inheritanceproblem\LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.method1_normal()".toLower());
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method toLower()
  location: class String
D:\workspace\Test\src\stackoverflow\lombok\inheritanceproblem\LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.method2_normal()".toLower());
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method toLower()
  location: class String
D:\workspace\Test\src\stackoverflow\lombok\inheritanceproblem\LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.method3_final()".toLower());
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   method toLower()
  location: class String
4 errors
```

Weirdest thing is, that those problems are raised in the file `LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass`.
When compiling `LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass` as the target, those problems did not arise.

So what am I doing wrong?

- Do I need to add additional stuff to the classpath?
- Is it the sequence/order of items for the javac compilation command that pose a problem?
- Am I missing some annotations inside my .java files?

Comment: Usually, you must compile all three classes: `javac <your option> AOPString.java LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass.java LombokInheritanceProblem_ChildClass.java`. If I do so, it works fine. What lombok version and what Java version do you use?

Comment: I've tried compiling with Oracle `jdk1.8.0_181`, GraalVM `graalvm-ce-java8-21.0.0.2` and `graalvm-ce-java11-21.0.0.2`. Exact same results. When I only specify the main-class file, my method (only 1 target files) also compiles huge projects (output size 2+ mb). But I think we've come close to the problem: lombok only pre-processes explicitly addressed files. When I target both _ChildClass.java and _BaseClass.java, all compiles fine. Even when I leave out AOPString. Lombok still finds that on its own.

Comment: Basically I don't want to compile files that are not needed, and was afraid of hitting max command line length (32768 characters) when doing so. Just found out though that I can pass all additional infos to the compiler via files. Still, I consider this a Lombok fail if it will include required files on its own, but won't preprocess files needed for inheritance...

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but it might not be a Lombok problem. Preprocessing is a feature of the Java compiler. Maybe this only preprocesses files given in the command.

Comment: Did you try to build with Maven/Gradle using Lombok plugin? I think the root of the problem is that just adding lombok.jar to classpath is not enough, you also need to instruct compiler that third-party annotation processor should be involved into build process

Comment: Are you using any user libraries in Eclipse? If so, those are in your Eclipse `.classpath` file, which explains why it works in Eclipse only. You will be better off building your project with something like Maven or Ant so that you could tie up all your dependencies. It is much easier to do that way than using plain `javac` command.

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko javac finds all preprocessors included in [files] and [classpath] and [sourcepath] before any compilation is done, and calls them. When I compile `LombokInheritanceProblem_BaseClass` it all works fine. So no problem with that.

Comment: @hfontanez yeah... Maven/Gradle/Ant/EclipseBuild... those are the REASONS I want to do it 'manually'. I'm actually writing a packager on my own, because 1) I really dislike those tools because they produce bloated output and 2) I need some specific additional features in 3) a fully portable manner. So nope, not an option. And that's why I need to hit javac 'manually'.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanx a lot for that idea! I will write a test preprocessor, introduce that into the build and check if that's the actual problem and how to solve intercepting required files from [sourcepath] for preprocessing... So in the end I may get a Lombok-pre-preprocessor^^

Comment: @hfontanez And YES, I use/include user libraries too. And that also works fine. But the example above has nothing to do with user libraries. The problem above is that Lombok will not preprocess files that are found on [sourcepath] (even when they're in the same directories as the compilation targets).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Okay wrote and tested my preprocessor yesterday. javac only passes files to it that are directly supplied as compilation targets, as in `javac [targets] ...`, and does not pass on resources found in [sourcepath]. Preprocessor would have to do dependency tests and processing on its own. So to solve my problem, I now build the dependency tree before I hit javac, and pass all required files that need Lombok proprocessing. Almost done even.

Comment: @JayC667 Then I recommend to post this analysis and your solution as an answer yourself. It might help others. Well done!